# How to get all the HTTP response headers of the current page in php

Tags: php, http, http-headers, httpresponse

`headers_list()` and `apache_reponse_headers()` return a greatly reduced list of the actual response headers, even after `headers_sent()` and `get_headers()` would make another HTTP request.

So, how can you get the complete list of response headers that are to be sent with the current page, or are these additional response headers, as set by the server, only set long after PHP has finished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hosting webserver is free to add headers. For example, it may transparently compress php's output, set [Strict-Transport-Security](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-02.txt) headers, and so on. In some setups (for example [wikimedia's](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_servers#System_architecture)), the request is also *proxied* by another HTTP server on another machine to allow caching.

Therefore, there is no way to get the complete list of sent HTTP headers. *Why* would you want to have that anyway?

Comment: This was really a debugging / curiosity exercise. I suppose I was just a bit surprised by how little info I could get within the current request - but that does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is most of the headers are sent by the server, not the PHP script itself. Sure, you can send headers inside a script, but that won't mean you'll get all the ones sent after the page has been loaded.